# XSLT is failing to filter

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have following XML

```
<XML>
<Header>
    <From>
        <Testing
            domain="testerID">
            <Identity>76w787w7-T</Identity>
        </Testing>
        <Testing domain="NetWorkid">
            <Identity>2382232-t</Identity>
        </Testing>
    </From>
 </Header>
</XML>
```

I am trying to implement the below logic

1) If any of domain has value = 'networkId' then final output will that particular Identity
   2) if none of domain is networkid , populate the first identity

XSL :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="Sender_ID"/>
<xsl:template match="XML">
    <OutputHeader>
        <xsl:for-each select="Header/From/Testing">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains('|Networkid|NetworkId|NetworkID|networkid|networkId|networkID|netWorkid|netWorkId|netWorkID||NETWORKID|NetWorkid|NetWorkId|NetWorkID|',concat('|',@domain,'|'))">
                <Sender>
                    <xsl:value-of  select="Identity" />
                </Sender>                    
            </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <Sender>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Identity[1]"/>
                    </Sender>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </OutputHeader>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Output :

`<OutputHeader>
   <Sender>2382232-t</Sender>
</OutputHeader>`

Actual Output :

`<OutputHeader>
   <Sender>76w787w7-T</Sender>
   <Sender>2382232-t</Sender>
</OutputHeader>`

Can you please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting both because you're doing an `xsl:for-each` over every `Testing` element.

You could try doing an `xsl:templates` to either the first `Testing/Identity` or the `Testing/Identity` that has a `@domain` that matches, whichever comes last.

Example...

**XML Input**

```
<XML>
    <Header>
        <From>
            <Testing
                domain="testerID">
                <Identity>76w787w7-T</Identity>
            </Testing>
            <Testing domain="NetWorkid">
                <Identity>2382232-t</Identity>
            </Testing>
        </From>
    </Header>
</XML>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="lower" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="upper" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*/Header/From">
        <OutputHeader>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="((Testing/Identity)[1]|Testing[translate(@domain,$upper,$lower)='networkid']/Identity)[last()]"/>
        </OutputHeader>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Identity">
        <Sender><xsl:value-of select="."/></Sender>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<OutputHeader>
   <Sender>2382232-t</Sender>
</OutputHeader>
```

Comment: I think you can drop the entire `<xsl:template match="/*/Header/From">` in exchange for an `<xsl:if test="'networkid' = translate(../@domain, $upper, $lower)">` in the other template.

Answer (score 1):

How about a simple one?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <OutputHeader>  
        <xsl:for-each select="XML/Header/From/Testing[@domain='NetWorkid']">
            <Sender><xsl:value-of select="Identity"/></Sender>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:if test="not(XML/Header/From/Testing[@domain='NetWorkid'])">
            <Sender>
                <xsl:value-of select="XML/Header/From/Testing[1]/Identity"/>
            </Sender>
        </xsl:if>
    </OutputHeader>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note: you didn't say what should happen if there are several instances of `<Testing domain="NetWorkid">`; the above will create a `<Sender>` element for each.

Comment: Part of the requirement seems to be case-insensitivity.

Comment: @Tomalak Right - and since it doesn't seem to be a part of the problem, I have cheerfully ignored it. :-)

Comment: That's fair enough. :)

Comment: If more than one domain with Networkid, We have to display first one.